# How convert a MySQL table to utf8 character set with alembic?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, alembic

My database is MySQL. I use SqlAlchemy ORM to define and access it. I use Alembic for migrations. I have a model with a field that used to contain just English text (Ascii/latin-1). Now, this field needs to contain Unicode text. In order to convert my model to support Unicode for MySQL I need to add the following class level attribute: **mysql_character_set = 'utf8'**

```
class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mymodel'
    mysql_character_set = 'utf8'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

So far so good. I want to add this attribute as part of an Alembic migration script. I normally use Alembic's excellent auto-generate command:

```
alembic revision --autogenerate
```

The problem is that this command doesn't capture every model change and in particular not the addition of the **mysql_character_set** attribute.

How do I add this attribute manually to the alembic migration script?

Comment: canyou try, am not sure.  create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://user:pass@host/dbname?charset=utf8&use_unicode=0")

Answer (score 4):

I did it like this:

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


def upgrade():
    conn = op.get_bind()
    conn.execute(sa.sql.text('ALTER table my_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci'))
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `utf8mb4` character set, as `utf8` (aka `utf8mb3`) is [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30074492/244297).

To change the default character set for a table **and** convert all character columns (`CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `TEXT`) to the new character set, you can use `ALTER TABLE` in a migration (but see the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-character-set) for possible side effects):

```
from alembic import op


def upgrade():
   op.execute(
       'ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
   )

def downgrade():
    op.execute(
        'ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just specify these parameters in your MyModel class. You'll need to create alembic migrations as well to incorporate those changes into DB.

`mysql_charset='utf8mb4', mysql_collate='utf8mb4_bin'`