# Check if String is Valid MySQL UTF8?

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, utf-8

I have a MySQL column encoded as utf8. That utf8 is not actually the full utf8 set, but [only BMP characters only up to 3 bytes in length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html). I don't want to try to insert utf8 into MySQL only to find it does not meet MySQL's parameters for what utf8 should be. Is there a way to test in Python if something meets MySQL's parameters before attempting to insert? For obvious reasons, catching exceptions on `some_string.encode('utf-8')` is not strict enough.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> len(u'\uffff'.encode('utf8')) < 4 # Good; fits in utf8
True
>>> len(u'\U00010000'.encode('utf8')) < 4 # Bad; utf8mb4 only
False
>>> ord(u'\uffff') < 65536 # Good; fits in utf8
True
>>> ord(u'\U00010000') < 65536 # Bad; utf8mb4 only
False
```

Answer (score 2):

To check whether a string contains a Unicode character above U+FFFF (and which thus can't be stored in a MySQL table using the "utf8" encoding), you can use the following regular expression:

```
re.match(u"[^\u0000-\uffff]", s)
```

Alternatively, if you can upgrade to MySQL 5.5 or later, you may want to consider converting your table to [the utf8mb4 character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html), which can store all Unicode characters.

Comment: You should use re.search instead of re.match, because when you try re.match("[^\u0000-\uffff]", "yura") it return None! but  re.search("[^\u0000-\uffff]", "yura") find this 
If you want to locate a match anywhere in string, use search() instead.