# Should I use utf8mb4 instead utf8?

Tags: utf-8, utf8mb4

What practical advantages and disadvantages does utf8mb4 provide, except ability to use Emoji? As I understand it takes more space to store.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between utf8mb4 and utf8 charsets in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql)

Comment: Is a good answer, but I believe there is more niceties using utf8mb4 and it would be good to have them in one place. I have read somewhere here that  comparing utf8mb4 and utf8 in MySQL will take much more time.

Answer (score 7):

utf8mb4 handles Emoji and some Chinese characters that are missing from utf8.  There are other, less common, characters.  Read about the [Unicode planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), realizing that the BMP is the only plane handled by MySQL's utf8.

As for space...  For characters that exist in utf8, utf8mb4 takes the same amount of space.