# Unable to enter Unicode data, MySql, Express, M*EAN

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js, unicode

I can insert english data no problem, but when I inserted Khmer Language, this error logs appears:

```
info: Session: { id: 1, username: john }
verbose: Executing (default): INSERT INTO `Articles` (`id`,`title`,`content`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`UserId`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'ថេាាថេា','ថេថេាថេាឹ','2016-07-08 09:50:28','2016-07-08 09:50:28',1);
verbose: Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `sid`, `data`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Sessions` AS `Session` WHERE `Session`.`sid` = 'Qzad_nN3rMR2RrsZ-Oa3H4A5BfL2optm' LIMIT 1;
Unhandled rejection RangeError: Invalid status code: 0
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:192:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:55:19)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:55:19)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:55:19)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:157:8)
    at ServerResponse.write (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/compression/index.js:83:14)
    at writetop (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/express-session/index.js:286:26)
    at ServerResponse.end (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/express-session/index.js:328:16)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:205:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:250:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:152:21)
    at .<anonymous> (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/app/controllers/articles.js:42:20)
    at tryCatcher (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:504:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:561:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
Unhandled rejection RangeError: Invalid status code: 0
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:192:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:55:19)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:55:19)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:55:19)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:157:8)
    at ServerResponse.end (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/compression/index.js:102:14)
    at writeend (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/express-session/index.js:257:22)
    at onsave (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/express-session/index.js:325:11)
    at .<anonymous> (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/express-sequelize-session/lib/e4store.js:90:51)
    at tryCatcher (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:504:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:561:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:681:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
error:  RangeError: Invalid status code: 0
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:192:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:55:19)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:55:19)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:55:19)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:157:8)
    at ServerResponse.end (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/compression/index.js:102:14)
    at writeend (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/express-session/index.js:257:22)
    at onsave (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/express-session/index.js:325:11)
    at .<anonymous> (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/express-sequelize-session/lib/e4store.js:88:51)
    at tryCatcher (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:504:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:561:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:685:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
Warning: Unexpected block "main"  on line 3 of /Users/Roller/Working/Web/mean-stack-relational/app/views/500.jade. This block is never used. This warning will be an error in v2.0.0
```

I was trying to remove database, and create a new one, still error shows.

What could be the issue? Please suggest.

Thanks,

Comment: what is an utf encoding type ?

Comment: how can i know about it?

Comment: You've given us *only* the error log. Ideally, give us also the structure of your database and just enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's perhaps worth mentioning that MySQL's `utf8` charset doesn't actually allow all of Unicode. [For all of Unicode, you need `utf8mb4`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30074553/209139).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: It's perhaps worth mentioning that MySQL's `utf8` charset doesn't actually allow all of Unicode. For all of Unicode, you need `utf8mb4`.

Comment: How did you know about it? Working superbly. Thanks!

Comment: (Khmer is available in both utf8 and utf8mb4.)