# How to change the connection collation of Mysql

Tags: mysql, collation

How can I change connection collation of mysql database?

I am using Mysql workbench 5.5 and mysql 5.5 in ubuntu 14.

When I execute a stored procedure, an error occurs:

> Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

I have search though the internet, which has a temp solution that is to amend

```
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

in the stored procedure.

But I want to fix this problem for all stored procedures in the future. I have found

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
```

which return this.

```
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  utf8_unicode_ci
collation_server    latin1_swedish_ci
```

how can I change `utf8_general_ci` to `utf8_unicode_ci`?

Comment: First of all, your MySQL Workbench version is way too old. Update it before retrying.

Comment: Let's see the query that got the error message, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table involved.  Also, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`.

Answer (score 14):

Look into your `my.cnf`, find the contents below near `collation_server`:

```
[mysqld]
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci'
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci 
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

Then change your collation variables to:

```
collation_connection    utf8_unicode_ci
collation_server        latin1_swedish_ci
```

Remember to restart MySQL server service.

For DB collation, you can use the following SQL:

```
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

or you can do it at Alter database screen in MySQL Workbench (always update this to the latest version!)

Comment: Keep in mind that `init_connect` is ignored when connecting as `root`.

Comment: What is the solution then if i connect using root

Comment: From the docs, *For users that have the CONNECTION_ADMIN or SUPER privilege, the content of init_connect is not executed. This is done so that an erroneous value for init_connect does not prevent all clients from connecting. For example, the value might contain a statement that has a syntax error, thus causing client connections to fail. Not executing init_connect for users that have the CONNECTION_ADMIN or SUPER privilege enables them to open a connection and fix the init_connect value.* If you connect using `root` and wish to use custom connection collation, please use a non-SUPER account.

Comment: Docs link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_connect

Comment: It should be noted that `utf8` is not actually UTF-8 in mysql collations. Use `utf8mb4` to use that. [What is the difference between utf8mb4 and utf8 charsets in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30074492/2415524)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think the error message is because of the collation of stored procedure (connection) doesn't match the table. But I was wrong, the reason for the error is because of the collation of the column doesn't match the collation of the table.

I want to change to collation of column to 'utf8_unicode_ci' in my case. So 
I have run this statement:

```
alter table <YourTableName> 
    MODIFY <YourColumnName> VARCHAR(XXX) COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';
```

Please be aware that change of collation may result in data loss. For me, General -> Unicode, with all English in `varchar` column. There is none.

Further reading:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-column.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-database.html