# Collation over DDEV TYPO3 instance

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, ddev

I got a TYPO3 8.7 instance running over a server whose database and tables collation is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. The character set is `utf8mb4`.

However, MySQL over the server shows the collation for the connection is `latin1_swedish_ci` and collation for the server is `utf8_general_ci` (I guess these are parameters that come pre-configured with the hosting):

```
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | latin1_swedish_ci  |
| collation_database   | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci    |
+----------------------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I would like to reproduce all these settings over my DDEV instance. I got the last two variable names properly configured with these settings over my `.ddev/mysql/no_utf8mb4.cnf` file:

```
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
character-set-server = utf8
```

But I cannot get the `collation_connection` as `latin1_swedish_ci`. How could I achieve that?

I exported my database from the hosting and imported it into ddev, but with the current configuration, every time I login into the backend, I receive an error like this:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO sys_log (userid, type, action, error, details_nr, details, log_data, tablename, recuid, IP, tstamp, event_pid, NEWid, workspace) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [1, 255, 1, 0, 1, "User %s logged in from %s (%s)", "a:3:{i:0;s:30:\"xxx@xxx.com\";i:1;s:10:\"172.18.0.6\";i:2;s:0:\"\";}", "", 0, "172.18.0.6", 1564691070, -1, "", -99]: Field 'request_id' doesn't have a default value
```

Has anyone experienced this issue?

My MariaDB version over my ddev instance is `10.1.37-MariaDB`.

Comment: I *think* the basic recipe you're looking for is https://stackoverflow.com/a/38949160/215713

Comment: I already tried this, @rfay, but the sentences:

Comment: I already tried this, @rfay, but the sentences first two sentences for init_connect don't take any effect.

Comment: Another thing was mentioned by @jonaseberle in TYPO3 channel, `ddev mysql --default-character-set=__whatever__` - `ddev mysql` is in just-released v1.10, but you could always do this by running the mysql client inside the web or db container.