# How to setup mysql with utf-8 using docker compose?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, docker-compose

I am trying to get my mysql image running with utf-8 encoding. My docker-compose file looks like:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    container_name: zoho-grabber-db-development
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=topsecret
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=development
      - MYSQL_USER=devuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secure
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

When i run it, it says

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.development.yml up
Removing zoho-grabber-db-development
Recreating 1b341fd7916e_1b341fd7916e_zoho-grabber-db-development

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"mysqld\": executable file not found in $PATH"
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Why is mysqld not found? And how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

When using `command` in `docker-compose.yml` it overrides the default `command` and `entrypoint` as described in the [docker-compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint). In order for you to achieve your goal, I suggest that you mount a `my.cnf` as a volume as described in the [docker image's readme](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) under section "Using a custom MySQL configuration file".

So remove `command` from your docker-compose and add `volumes` eg.

```
...
volumes:
  - mycustom.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf
...
```

and the container will include your custom configuration as the server's configuration

**Edit-1**

Below is the custom config the you need

**mycustom.cnf**

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

Comment: added the config needed also to complete the answer

Comment: @Norbert Egger There also is a section "Configuration without a cnf file" but I'm not sure how that would apply to docker-compose. Perhaps would be handy for manual runs

Comment: Thank you, it now works! I had do cleanup my docker (images and container) then rebuild everything and it worked.

Answer (score 34):

For new comers to this question, I was able to make it work by basically removing `mysqld` from `command: mysqld ...` like so:

```
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_general_ci
    restart: always
    environment:
```

This is the same way as in the [documentation for the official MySQL image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/), under section *... via docker stack deploy or docker-compose*.

---

As a sidenote, you **almost never** want `utf8` encoding in MySQL; you need `utf8mb4`. See this Q&A for more: [What is the difference between utf8mb4 and utf8 charsets in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30074553/2194007)

Comment: this is probably the fastest and easiest solution. On my side I just needed the `--character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_general_ci` without the `--default-authentication-plugin`

Answer (score 0):

Now that Mysql8's default collation is utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

```
mysql>  SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| @@character_set_database | @@collation_database |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| utf8mb4                  | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci   |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
```

We don't have to set character set and its collation.