# Encoding problem on MySQL: Why some non-ASCII characters get encoded on more than 4 bytes?

Tags: mysql, docker, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I've encountered a problem using MySQL on Docker. When I directly insert non-ASCII characters in the database using the initialization sql script, the characters are correctly shown on MySQL's console, but their encodings are wrong.

I coded a MySQL container with a minimal sql script to reproduce the problem.

Here's the structure of my directory:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── my-sql
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── ddl
        └── mySQL.sql
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services: 
 mysql:
     build:
       context: ./my-sql/
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
     container_name: mysql
     expose:
       - 3306
     ports:
       - 3306:3306
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
       MYSQL_USER: test
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
       MYSQL_DATABASE: test
     volumes:
       - "mysql:/var/lib/mysql"

volumes:
 mysql:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mysql:8.2.0

USER 999:999

COPY ./ddl /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

mySQL.sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`(
    `test` VARCHAR(100)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `test` (`test`) VALUES ("");
INSERT INTO `test` (`test`) VALUES ("平");

ALTER DATABASE test CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci; # Does not work
```

When I use MySQL using the console and that I select the test column of the test table, I get this:

```
mysql> SELECT `test` FROM `test`;
+------+
| test |
+------+
|  |
| 平  |
+------+
```

```
mysql> SELECT HEX(`test`) FROM `test`;
+------------------+
| HEX(`test`)      |
+------------------+
| C3B0C5B8C2A4C2AE |
| C3A5C2B9C2B3     |
+------------------+
```

I did some research to find the correct encoding of these characters in various encodings and I didn't see these encodings, and as far as my knowledges go, maximum size for UTF-8 character is 4 bytes. I also noticed that the "|" alignment of what MySQL prints is wrong (and proportionally wronger to the size of the character hexadecimal encoding).

I looked at the hexadecimal encoding of the .sql script using VScode and, at least, the emoji is correctly encoded (F0 9F A4 AE).

I also tried another MySQL version (8.0.36), but it still doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ```SELECT UNHEX(HEX(`test`)) FROM `test`;``` -> ?

Comment: That looks to me like it's double-encoded.  The first line decodes to a sequence of Unicode code points U+00F0 U+0178 U+00A4 U+00AE, which is almost-but-not-quite what you're showing as the expected UTF-8 encodeing.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for you answer. `SELECT UNHEX(HEX(\`test\`)) FROM \`test\``; returns exactly the same thing as `SELECT HEX(\`test\`) FROM \`test\``; (So the hexadecimal encoding of the emoji and the kanji). I don't really know how to interpret this ... UNHEX(HEX(\`test\`)) should return the values in \`test\`, isn't it ?

Comment: *UNHEX(HEX(`test`)) should return the values in `test`, isn't it ?* Yes, it must return `test` column value.

Comment: Definitely a double-encoding issue. `` in UTF-8 is bytes `F0 9F A4 AE`, which when interpreted in Windows-1252 yields Unicode codepoints `U+00F0 U+0178 U+00A4 U+00AE`, which in UTF-8 is bytes `C3 B0 C5 B8 C2 A4 C2 AE` - exactly what is being seen in the output. Same with `平`, which in UTF-8 is bytes `E5 B9 B3`, which when interpreted as Windows-1252 yields codepoints `U+00E5 U+00B9 U+00B3`, which in UTF-8 is bytes `C3 A5 C2 B9 C2 B3`. So, simply hexing and unhexing is not enough, as there is a 2nd charset at play which is mis-interpreting and re-encoding the original UTF-8 bytes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh ok, I understand. Thanks you very much. I looked for double encoding problem on mysql and docker and I found this Stackoverflow topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004648/how-to-setup-mysql-with-utf-8-using-docker-compose and it solves my problem (at least for the minimal mysql script I provided).

Comment: That's "double encoding".  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored