# Compromised saveguard of data due to bad encoding usage?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, phpmyadmin, wamp, jupyter

I am using jupyter & python 3.6.4 via anaconda.
I want to be able to process and store data from python to a MySQL database.
The libraries I am using to do this are`pymysql` and `sqlalchemy`.

For now, I am testing this localy with `wamp` (`mysql version : 5.7.21`), later I will apply it to a distant server.

Database creation function:

```
def create_raw_mysql_db(host,user,password,db_name):
    conn=pymysql.connect(host=host,user=user,password=password)
    conn.cursor().execute('DROP DATABASE '+db_name)
    conn.cursor().execute('CREATE DATABASE '+db_name+' CHARACTER SET utf8mb4')
```

Function to convert a Dataframe to a relational table in MySql:

```
def save_raw_to_mysql_db(df,table_name,db_name,if_exists,username,password,host_ip,port):
    engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://"+username+":@"+host_ip+":"+port+"/"+db_name+"?charset=utf8mb4")
    df.to_sql(name=table_name,con=engine,if_exists=if_exists,chunksize=10000)
```

The execution code:

```
#DB info & credentials
host = "localhost"
port = "3306"
user= "root"
password= ""
db_name= "raw_data"
exade_light_tb = "exade_light"

#A simple dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 5)),columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])


create_raw_mysql_db(host,user,password,db_name)
save_raw_to_mysql_db(df,exade_light_tb,db_name,"replace",user,password,host,port)
```

The warning I receive when I run this code:

> C:\Users.... : Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\x92\xE9t\xE9)' for column 'VARIABLE_VALUE' at row 481")
>     result = self._query(query)

From these threads: [/questions/34165523/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165523/error-1366-hy000-incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x98-x9c-for-column-comme) [questions/47419943](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419943/pymysql-warning-1366-incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x98-x8d-t) [questions/2108824/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108824/mysql-incorrect-string-value-error-when-save-unicode-string-in-django), I could conclude the problem must be related to the utf8 charset, but I am using utf8mb4 to create my db and I am not using Django (which supposedly also needed to be configured according to [questions/2108824/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108824/mysql-incorrect-string-value-error-when-save-unicode-string-in-django)).

My questions :

1. How is this warning really impacting my data and its integrity?
2. How come even though I change charset from utf8 to utf8mb4, it
   doesn't seem to solve the warning? Do I need to configure something
   further? In this case, what are the parameters I should keep in mind
   to apply the same configuration to my distant server?
3. How do I get rid of this warning?

Annex:

[image: Phpmyadmin shows the right encoding is being used]