# General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8D\xB8 !...'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, utf8mb4

The following error appears when a user sends a message containing an emoji (precisely, when the message is stored in MySql database) :

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string
>   value: '\xF0\x9F\x8D\xB8 !...' for column 'message' at row 1 in ...

I already check the following questions:

- [PyMySQL Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x8D t...')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419943/pymysql-warning-1366-incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x98-x8d-t)
- [java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x91\xBD\xF0\x9F...'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653712/java-sql-sqlexception-incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x91-xbd-xf0-x9f)
- [ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x9C' for column 'comment' at row 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165523/error-1366-hy000-incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x98-x9c-for-column-comme)
- [Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8E\xB6\xF0\x9F...' MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411440/incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x8e-xb6-xf0-x9f-mysql)

All the previous questions propose the same answer : altering the table to 
`utf8mb4` typeset. This is what I did : I changed my table and the concerned column to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

But the problem still appears. Any idea ?

Comment: When you open a connection to the db, do you run something like `SET NAMES utf8` by any chance? If so, change it to `SET NAMES utf8mb4`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Setting your column and table to utf8mb4 is fine, however additional settings are needed for things to work smoothly :

PDO connection :

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=my_ip;dbname=my_db;charset=utf8mb4';
```

SQL order to run after connecting and before running queries :

```
$conn->exec("set names utf8mb4");
```