# SQLAlchemy with pooling not closing database connections

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, sqlalchemy

I discovered that SQLAlchemy does not release the database connections (in my case) so this piles up to the point that it might crash the server. The connections are made from different threads.

Here is the simplified code

```py
"""
Test to see DB connection allocation size while making call from multiple threads
"""

from time import sleep
from threading import Thread, current_thread
import uuid

from sqlalchemy import func, or_, desc
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, Column, Integer, String, DateTime, UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, DateTime, String, Boolean, Text, Float
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool

# MySQL
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE = 'mysql'
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://amalgam:amalgam@localhost/amalgam?charset=utf8mb4' # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47419943/pymysql-warning-1366-incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x98-x8d-t
SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = False
SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {'pool_size': 40, 'max_overflow': 0}
SQLALCHEMY_ISOLATION_LEVEL = "AUTOCOMMIT"

# DB Engine

# engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, echo=SQLALCHEMY_ECHO, pool_recycle=3600,
#                        isolation_level= SQLALCHEMY_ISOLATION_LEVEL,
#                        **SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS
#                        ) #  Connect to server

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, 
                        echo=SQLALCHEMY_ECHO, 
                        # poolclass=NullPool,
                        pool_recycle=3600,
                       isolation_level= SQLALCHEMY_ISOLATION_LEVEL,
                       **SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS
                       ) #  Connect to server


session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()

# ORM Entity
class User(Base):

    LEVEL_NORMAL = 'normal'
    LEVEL_ADMIN = 'admin'

    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)    
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    email = Column(String(100), nullable=True, unique=True)
    password = Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    level = Column(String(100), default=LEVEL_NORMAL)


# Workers
NO = 10
workers = []

_scoped_session_factory = scoped_session(session_factory)


def job(job_id):
    session = _scoped_session_factory()

    print("Job is {}".format(job_id))

    user = User(name='User {} {}'.format(job_id, uuid.uuid4()), email='who cares {} {}'.format(job_id, uuid.uuid4()))

    session.add(user)
    session.commit()
    session.close()

    print("Job {} done".format(job_id))
    sleep(10)
    
# Create worker threads
for i in range(NO):
    workers.append(Thread(target=job, kwargs={'job_id':i}))

# Start them
for worker in workers:
    worker.start()

# Join them
for worker in workers:
    worker.join()

# Allow some time to see MySQL's "show processlist;" command
sleep(10)
```

The moment the program reaches

```py
sleep(10)
```

and I run the

```sql
show processlist;
```

it give the following result - meaning that all connections to the DB are still alive.

[image]

**How can I force closing those connections?**

*Note*: I could make use of

```py
poolclass=NullPool
```

but I feel that that solution is too restrictive - I would like to still have access to a database pool but being able to somehow close connections when wanted

Answer (score 5):

The following is from the [signature for `QueuePool` constructor](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/pooling.html?highlight=max_overflow#sqlalchemy.pool.QueuePool.__init__)

> pool_size – The size of the pool to be maintained, defaults to 5. This
> is the largest number of connections that will be kept persistently in
> the pool. Note that the pool begins with no connections; once this
> number of connections is requested, that number of connections will
> remain. pool_size can be set to 0 to indicate no size limit; to
> disable pooling, use a `NullPool` instead.
>
> max_overflow – The maximum overflow size of the pool. When the number
> of checked-out connections reaches the size set in pool_size,
> additional connections will be returned up to this limit. When those
> additional connections are returned to the pool, they are disconnected
> and discarded. It follows then that the total number of simultaneous
> connections the pool will allow is pool_size + max_overflow, and the
> total number of “sleeping” connections the pool will allow is
> pool_size. max_overflow can be set to -1 to indicate no overflow
> limit; no limit will be placed on the total number of concurrent
> connections. Defaults to 10.

```py
SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {'pool_size': 40, 'max_overflow': 0}
```

Given the above, this configuration is *asking* SQLAlchemy to keep up to 40 connections open.

If you don't like that, but want to keep some connections available you might try a configuration like this:

```py
SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {'pool_size': 10, 'max_overflow': 30}
```

This will keep 10 persistent connections in the pool, and will burst up to 40 connections if requested concurrently. Any connection in surplus of the configured pool size are immediately closed upon being checked back into the pool.

Comment: You mention "upon being checked back into the pool". How do you do that in ORM, call session.close()?

Comment: Yep that's right. Also I'd imagine that if the session runs out of references the connection would be automatically released back into the pool as well