# How take mysqldump with UTF8?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to take mysql dump with command:

```
mysqldump -u xxxx -p dbxxx > xxxx270613.sql
```

what is command to take mysqldump with UTF8 ?

Comment: What do you mean by "take mysqldump with UTF8"? Whats the problem?

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://makandracards.com/makandra/595-dumping-and-importing-from-to-mysql-in-an-utf-8-safe-way?

Comment: @NicoHaase I was facing problem when I was importing sql file. There are some restrictions with other character set's. So There is standard with UTF8 and It fixes lot of mysql import issues.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
mysqldump -u [username] –p[password] --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -N --routines --skip-triggers --databases [database_name] > [dump_file.sql]
```

Comment: Never use `utf8`; as of 2021 use nothing less than `utf8mb4`.

Comment: @John Why? Can you please explain?

Comment: @RaulChiarella You need to use `utf8mb4`, not `utf` or a lot of UTF characters will get corrupted. Example: **HTTP GET Request**: `SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'`, **HTTP POST Requests**: `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4'`.

Comment: Thanks. I will use utf8mb4 from now on.

Comment: Here's an explanation of utf8 (utff8mb3) vs utf8mb4: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30074553

Answer (score 21):

I had the problem, that even with applied utf-8 flags when creating the dump I could not avoid broken characters importing a dump that was created from a DB with many text columns using latin1. 
Some googling and especially [this site](https://www.whitesmith.co/blog/latin1-to-utf8/) helped me to finally figure it out.

1. mysqldump with **--skip-set-charset --default-character-set=latin1** flags, 
   to avoid MySQL attempt of reconversion and setting a charset.
2. fix the dump by replacing the charset strings using sed on terminal

   sed -i 's/latin1_swedish_ci/utf8mb4/g' mysqlfile.sql
   sed -i 's/latin1/utf8mb4/g' mysqlfile.sql

to make sure you don't miss anything you can do grep -i 'latin1' mysqlfile.sql before step 2 - and then come up with more sed orders. Introduction to sed [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-text-in-files-in-linux-unix-shell/)

3. create a clean DB

   CREATE DATABASE mydatabase CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
4. apply fixed dump

Comment: Thank you for this !  It fixed my issue.

Comment: Wow, incredible answer, upvoted!  It's unbelievable that setting `default-character-set=utf8` would actually cause utf-8 corruption, thank you!

Comment: Incredible answer [2]. Worked beautifully! Thanks

Answer (score 15):

`--default-character-set=utf8` is the option you are looking for the one can be used together with these others:

```
mysqldump --events \
 --routines \
 --triggers \
 --add-drop-database \
 --compress \
 --hex-blob \
 --opt \
 --skip-comments \ 
 --single-transaction \
 --skip-set-charset \
 --default-character-set=utf8 \
 --databases dbname > my.dump
```

Also, check the `--hex-blob` it helps to dump binary strings in hexadecimal format, so I can guaranty (be more portable) making the import to work.

> The `--databases` option causes all names on the command line to be treated as database names. Without this option, `mysqldump` treats the first name as a database name and those following as table names.
>
> With `--all-databases` or `--databases`, `mysqldump` writes `CREATE DATABASE` and `USE` statements prior to the dump output for each database. This ensures that when the dump file is reloaded, it creates each database if it does not exist and makes it the default database so database contents are loaded into the same database from which they came. If you want to cause the dump file to force a drop of each database before recreating it, use the --add-drop-database option as well. In this case, `mysqldump` writes a `DROP DATABASE` statement preceding each `CREATE DATABASE` statement.

This helps to restore using:

```
# mysql < dump.sql
```

Instead of:

```
# mysql dbname < dump.sql
```

Comment: Never use `utf8`; as of 2021 use nothing less than `utf8mb4`.