# Force mysqldump to use CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I've been going through the [mysqldump documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/) for MariaDB.

How do I force `mysqldump` to output `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS`?

The best I've managed is to add the `--databases` flag:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --skip-set-charset --databases --default-character-set=latin1 database_name > /home/database_name.sql
```

However that outputs the following:

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `database_name` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci */;
```

I can't have the `IF NOT EXISTS` commented out. What am I missing?

Also: because someone is going to need to make a comment about it: the `latin1` character set is a fix for the `No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page` error message that can be [solved by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62309115/606371) *if* you also follow through with the two terminal commands.

Comment: Why do you want to have `IF NOT EXISTS` commented out?

Comment: @GeorgRichter I explicitly *do NOT* want it commented out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment `/*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS */` is only interpreted as a comment, if you use MySQL Version < 3.23.12 (which was released in the previous millennium).

For more details please check the ["Comment syntax"](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/comment-syntax/) in the MariaDB Knowledge Base.

Comment: I really had to read that - so in short MariaDB and MySQL support syntax *inside of comments*. That is akin to Internet Explorer's conditional comments from IE 5.5 to IE10. So what is happening here is that code tells MariaDB to not run that snippet if it doesn't match that version of greater which is odd because it lacks the periods and thus is wildly open to interpretation. So the code will run as `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS` as long as it's greater than version 3.23.12.