# mariadb-dump with database name containing unicode characters?

Tags: windows, unicode, command-line, mariadb, database-backups

Trying to author a `mariadb-dump.exe` command line to back up our MariaDB 10.11 databases on Windows (Swedish locale, win-1252 system codepage). Unfortunately we expect full unicode support and named a database so it contains Swedish character "ö".

I tried this command line:

```
mariadb-dump.exe --user=root --password=XXX --opt --result-file=backup.sql --default-character-set=utf8mb4 --quote-names dbföretag FirstTable SecondTable
```

I get this error:

```
mariadb-dump.exe: Error: 'Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb3_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='' when trying to dump tablespaces
mariadb-dump.exe: Got error: 1300: "Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'dbf\xF6retag'" when selecting the database
```

I am trying to resolve the second error, which seems to indicate that `mariadb-dump.exe` fails to correctly encode the database name when sending it to the server, or the server incorrectly interprets the string when received.

I tried `chcp 65001` in the `cmd.exe` session before running `mariadb-dump.exe`, but I get the exact same result.

The character "ö" has unicode codepoint U+00F6, which matches `\xF6` in the error message, but UTF-8 encodes it as 0xC3 0xB6. Since I get this same result regardless of which `chcp` I use in the `cmd.exe` session, I conclude that `mariadb-dump.exe` correctly interprets the command line and understands that the "ö" is unicode codepoint U+00F6.

But it seems to fail to convert it into the encoding that should be sent to the server. Instead of encoding U+00F6 into utf-8 `\xC3\xB6` it passes the unicode codepoint without conversion, as `\xF6`. I fail to see how that could work regardless of encoding. Is there ANY unicode encoding that uses 1 byte per character up to and including code point U+00F6?

As a work around I am able to artificially create the correct utf-8 string by passing on the commnad line the two characters with unicode code points U+00C3 and U+00B6, i.e. using characters `Ã¶`. Since it's the unicode code points of those characters that matter and not how they are encoded in the `cmd.exe` session's code page, these two characters give the correct result regardless of which code page is being used in the `cmd.exe` session.

So, this command line works:

```
mariadb-dump.exe --user=root --password=XXX --opt --result-file=backup.sql --default-character-set=utf8mb4 --quote-names dbfÃ¶retag FirstTable SecondTable
```

Is there any way I can get `mariadb-dump.exe` to encode the database name into utf-8 correctly?

I tried adding these lines to `my.ini`, but it doesn't help:

```
[client]
character_set_connection=utf8mb4
collation_connection=utf8mb4_bin
```

Is this a bug in `mariadb-dump.exe`? In the server? In the MariaDB client library being used by `mariadb-dump.exe`? Or what?

UPDATE: Bug reported to MariaDB: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-32264

UPDATE: As can be read in the answers to the bug report above, the current implementation is said to work in newer Windows versions, and the one we have (Server 2019) will be out of mainstream support soon and it would be a significant effort to fix it so it works with that old Windows version. So, they won't fix anything. Instead, we will plan an upgrade to Server 2022 and hope that the problem will go away. In the meantime, using a work around.

Comment: Any input re. the first error message is also welcome, although not really the subject of this question.

Comment: You shpould always use the same version of zhe database ad then upgrade, but you can open the my.cnf/ini and look for the default character set collation and change it to utf8mb3 and utf8mb3_general_ci

Comment: if you have a linux system you can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/62309115/5193536

Comment: Apparently it works if I write the database name as `dbfÃ¶retag`, because `Ã` has codepoint U+00C3 and `¶` has codepoint U+00B6. This works regardless of which codepage I use in the `cmd.exe` session (tried 850 and 65001). Is this a bug that I should report? Is it in `mariadb-dump.exe` or in the server itself?

Comment: @nbk Your second comment addresses problems with utf-8 data inside the database and/or table names etc. with unicode names. That is not my problem. I'm having problems to even get the dump command to execute at all and the problem is only with the database name. My config already specifies `character-set-server=utf8mb4` and `character-set-filesystem=latin1`.

Comment: msdos can not use utf8, so you should avoid, that characters

Comment: @nbk It's `cmd.exe` in modern Windows (not MS-DOS) and it sure does support utf-8. You just need to run `chcp 65001`. Used it many times and still using it, in other contexts.

Comment: the command shell is  msdos ind windows since windows 1.0 with he same 8.3 amnd ascii restrictions

Comment: @nbk I have been working with `cmd.exe` in utf-8 mode (codepage 65001) for years and it works nicely, e.g. running bat files with utf-8 encoding, redirecting output to text/log files in utf-8 encoding etc. For the problem in this case, the codepage being used doesn't seem to matter. `mariadb-dump.exe` correctly converts the "ö" on the command line to unicode code point U+00F6 and enters it into the string as \xF6. The problem is that some other step (the server?) expects utf-8 encoding and not the unicode codepoint directly, which is \xC3\xB6.

Comment: @nbk If I do `chcp 850`, `echo ö > 850.txt` and then `chcp 65001`, `echo ö > 65001.txt`, then 850.txt contains \x94 which is ö in code page 850, while 65001 contains \xC3\xB6 which is ö in utf-8 encoding. This proves that `cmd` does support utf-8 encoding by use of `chcp 65001` and that the behavior we see with `mariadb-dump.exe` is not caused by `cmd` but by `mariadb-dump.exe`, the MariaDB server, or some client/interface layer. The command line from `cmd.exe` to `mariadb-dump.exe` is correctly interpreted as the unicode character U+00F6 in both cases. It's what happens next that's wrong.

Comment: Is there any way I can control which character set is to be used for the connection from `mariadb-dump.exe` to the server? I found `character_set_connection` but if I set that to utf8mb4 (same as `character-set-server`) under `[mysqld]` then MariaDB service fails to start. If I move the setting to `[client]` the service does start but `mariadb-dump.exe` gives the exact same two errors.

Comment: yes in a "normal" connection you can define the character set but nariadbdump has not such option, like i said use linux with the link provided to change the complete file, it takes some time to get it right, but it works. the rest you can read in my first comment

Comment: @nbk As I said before, the SO you linked is about table names, column names and data values getting corrupted. I tested and have no problems with those, so that SO answer is irrelevant. The only problem I have is with specifying a database name (and table names) on the *command line* to `mariadb-dump.exe`. I don't have a Linux machine at hand and don't know Linux at all and I can't see that it would help compared to the work-around I already found.

Comment: Bug submitted to MariaDB: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-32264

Comment: Let me clarify what happens here. mariadb-dump is a C++ program, which gets its arguments from the main() function. The arguments encoded using ANSI codepage, and it does not matter how much you "chcp" . The ANSI codepage is likely win-1252, mostly latin1. In that codepage ö corresponds to the byte 0xf6. mariadb-dump connects to the database server, using incorrectly encoded dbname- it tells the server, it is using UTF-8, but dbname is latin1. On newer Windows, ANSI codepage for MariaDB executables is UTF-8, so 0xf6 won't be sent with dbname, but correct UTF-8 byte sequence instead.