# query emoji in mysql confused me, mysql configured with utf8mb4 already

Tags: mysql, emoji

See the attached pic for details, mysql is configured with utf8mb4, anyone can tell me the reason. It seems all these emojis behave the same in database. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCRC8.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between utf8mb4 and utf8 charsets in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql)

Comment: @ObsidianAge but the point is that I have already set the mysql to support utf8mb4, and the query displayed in pic confused me.

Comment: Let's see the connection parameters.