# cause of \xF0\x9F\x98\x94 incorrect string value sql exception?

Tags: mysql, grails

In the log there is following error. The error occurs when a string \xF0\x9F\x98\x94 is passed as argument. This value cannot be saved to the table so it throws incorrect string value error. I am wondering what is the cause of passing such value. Is it a hacking attempt? I donot know what \xF0\x9F\x98\x94 means when passed as post form param. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

```
ERROR 2018-08-19 16:14:40,369 [ajp-bio-8109-exec-2808] util.JDBCExceptionReporter: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x94 B...' for column 'body' at row 1
ERROR 2018-08-19 16:14:40,372 [ajp-bio-8109-exec-2808] events.PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not update: [EventEmailDraft#42]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x94 B...' for column 'body' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4098)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2134)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2434)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2352)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2337)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    ... 3 more
ERROR 2018-08-19 16:14:40,377 [ajp-bio-8109-exec-2808] errors.GrailsExceptionResolver: SQLException occurred when processing request: [POST] /roadrace/message/saveDraft
Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x94 B...' for column 'body' at row 1. Stacktrace follows:
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: could not update: [EventEmailDraft#42]; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [update event_email_draft set version=?, body=?, emails=?, event_id=?, subject=? where id=? and version=?]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [1366]; Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x94 B...' for column 'body' at row 1; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x94 B...' for column 'body' at row 1
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x94 B...' for column 'body' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4098)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2134)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2434)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2352)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2337)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Unicode sequence consisting of more than 3 bytes

```
groovy:000> new String([0xF0, 0x9F, 0x98, 0x94] as byte[], 'UTF-8')
===>
```

The default for UTF-8 in MySQL is only to hold 3 bytes.

A proper explanation can be found here [What is the difference between utf8mb4 and utf8 charsets in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql#30074553) and the follow up questions like "how do I change that" are answered here too.

Comment: And of course the cynic in me will tell you that the best fix is to ditch MySQL ;P

Comment: Thanks i just checked the collation for the column body and it was latin1_swedish_ci. Could this have caused the error? if it was utf-8 i assume there wouldnt be any error? is there any harm in converting to utf-8? Thanks!

Comment: Those collation only make sense (if at all) for free text columns.  Be aware, that `utf8_unicode_ci` makes _lots_ of things appear equal.