# Suddenly MYSQL "Malformed packet" on LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE after two years of working

Tags: php, mysql, file, mysqli, import

This has been a nightly job working for two years. PHP file imports a txt file into MYSQL database. Suddenly today getting Malformed Packet when importing a TXT file. I noticed the server has only been up 23 hours, so I think GoDaddy could have updated something.

MYSQL Ver = 5.6.43-cll-lve

local_infile = ON

Without "local" I get error, "Access denied for user", I've tried granting FILE but having issues getting mysql CLI access via SSH (never needed it before) and PHP MY Admin doesn't have access rights.

I've spent an entire day on this, and can't figure out what to do. I have tried setting the file to 777 as well.

I've tried removing the truncate part and just doing the import, culling the import file down to 3 lines, using old import files that worked before-- can't make heads or tails.

```
require('config_dev.php');
$path = '/home/pro/public_html/upload/IDUpload_dev.txt';
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname,$username, $password, $dbname);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
  die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$sql1 = "TRUNCATE TABLE Accounts;";

if (!$mysqli->query($sql1)) {
    echo "\nQuery execute failed: ERRNO: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
} else {
    echo ("Truncated<br>");
}

$sql2 = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$path."' INTO TABLE Accounts
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        IGNORE 1 LINES
        (acct,type,zip)";

if (!$mysqli->query($sql2)) {
    echo "\nQuery execute failed: ERRNO: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
} else {
    echo ("Imported.");
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: *"I noticed the server has only been up 23 hours, so I think GoDaddy could have updated something."* So contact GoDaddy first to ask if they updated something.

Comment: Their low level support is not going to know anything at all. That's not going to help.

Comment: *"Their low level support is not going to know anything at all. That's not going to help"* Well we can't access there server and also don't know what they updated now do we? So posting here also will not really help... Maybe spend some more money to take a service by a better webhosting where the support is better then?

Comment: :( It's way more likely that my code is wrong than GoDaddy's servers are somehow to blame, even if they did update. Really just need some help, but thanks for your comments.

Comment: @RaymondNijland See helpful comment/solution below in case you need to help someone else in the future.

Comment: In general PHP Code does not sudden stop working after two year without a reason GoDaddy did a software (PHP, MySQL) upgrade or a configuration change what messed up the code execution.. Well i could have asked you do do some thinks like `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and `SHOW VARIABLES` in MySQL, to find out what the problem was but you said already that the `local_infile = ON` on GoDaddy's server..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use `LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL` the [MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php) needs to be enabled before connection.

You should `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile'` to see if this is enabled on the server which is also required.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that and can see that "local_infile ON".

Comment: BUT I didn't understand your first line, I just did the SHOW Vars... I searched for that specifically and adding this: mysqli_options($mysqli, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true); after the init WORKED! I love you! What could have changed from two years of working till last night?

Comment: The default connection options changed somehow, no idea. Maybe GoDaddy manually compiled the default to be different. Wouldn't surprise me. Make sure you undo your file permission and grant hackery.

Comment: Yes file permissions were just to test and never got SSH access so no grants'. Seriously, saved the day. I must have read every post out there, and specifically searching for mysqli load local, somehow never came across that. Let me know how to buy you a beer!

Comment: Nice catch @danblack i think `phpinfo()` also would not have exposed `mysqli_options()` so you could have see what was wrong.. Also PHP does not have a native function to see with what  `mysqli_options()` PHP connects.

Comment: *"The default connection options changed somehow, no idea. Maybe GoDaddy manually compiled the default to be different"* @Ben that was precisely the reason why you should have contacted GoDaddy first, they also could have removed `LOAD FILE` feature completly from the PHP and MySQL source codes before compiling a “Malformed packet” error might also have suggested that.

Comment: Actually, the Malformed packet in my case is because user doesn't have privilege to access files (LOCAL didn't fix the problem). https://stackoverflow.com/a/66504584/10533962

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to give the current user privilege to access files:

Login to `mysql` first:

`mysql -u root -p`

then

`GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost';`

Comment: Good catch. Think there needs to be a revamp of the error messages offered however.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, a script that worked fine for 3 years and suddenly starts to fail with "Malformed packet". I am running on an OVH hosted-server with a [private database](https://www.ovh.com/world/web-hosting/sql-options.xml).

Sadly, none of the solutions worked (`GRANT` or `MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE`).

After fiddling around, I noticed that the script worked on the test database on the same server!

I compared the two databases configuration, and the only difference I could find was on the **database collation**.

- On the test database, I had `SELECT @@collation_database` == `latin1_swedish_ci`
- On the production database which was no longer working, I had `SELECT @@collation_database` == `utf8_unicode_ci`

I changed the collation of the production database...

```sql
ALTER DATABASE DB_PROD_NAME CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

<s>**And it worked!** (even though all tables uses `utf8_unicode_ci`)</s>

Well, it works but all characters are mangled.

But it forces me to look into encoding issue, which lead me to the proper solution.

Using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ... CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' ...` I was able to get the real error:

```
ERROR : Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x93\x8B' for column ...
```

The [`\xF0\x9F\x93\x8B` value is actually a perfectly fine UTF8-encoded character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4cb/index.htm): the clipboard emoji

However, it is defined on 4 bytes (like most emojis).

As stated earlier, my tables and columns use the collation `utf8_unicode_ci`. So it should be good right? Except... not! The `utf8` implementation of mySQL is deeply flawed as it only allows to represents UTF8 up to 3 bytes! [See](https://www.eversql.com/mysql-utf8-vs-utf8mb4-whats-the-difference-between-utf8-and-utf8mb4/) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql) [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci) for more background.

The new and correct modern implementation of UTF8 in mySQL is called `utf8mb4`.

So the final solution was simply to migrate all tables and columns to the `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` collation and voila! Problem solved.

In the end, the biggest problem was understanding what exactly this very misleading "Malformed packet" error message meant.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution was really simple.

I totally agree with @danblack answer.

I added this line to my PHP script:

```
@mysqli_options($con, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
```

Just before the Insert script.