# Remove Emoji on MariaDB Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, emoji

I'm trying to remove emoji on Select query. I'm using MariaDB 10.3.14

Here's what I came up so far, but it doesn't work. It echoes all the string.

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE("<çşığ_loremipsumdolor", '/([\x10000-\x10FFFF]+)/g', '')
```

There will be some non-English, even some HTML tags in the actual string.

What I want to achieve from this string is `<çşığ_loremipsumdolor`.

How do I remove emoji from string using MariaDB 10.3?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex looks correct. I think the problem here is MariaDB itself. There exists a confirmed issue regarding the underlying cause: [MDEV-11777](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11777)

As an ugly workaround you could convert the text to utf8 (see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql) for some details why this works). This will show emojis and other characters as a `?`.

Afterwards you just remove the `?`.

So as a complete example:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(convert('<çşığ_loremipsumdolor' USING utf8),'\\?','');
```

This will give you `<çşığ_loremipsumdolor`.

It will of course also replace any actual question marks from the string. But I am sure this can be worked around as well (e.g. by replacing the wanted question mark by a placeholder, then removing the unwanted question marks and replacing the placeholder with a question marks again).

Unfortunately, it all sounds like something I would not do in SQL.