# Special characters in Wordpress not showing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been searching everywhere and tried a few things to solve this issue but I havent found anything, the url is clinicapacifico.cl and even though the db charset is set to utf8, the database and tables are also UTF8 and the table contents display the special characters with no problems, the site still wont show the special characters. If I edit the blocks inside wordpress the special characters also show ok.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be the DB_CHARSET and/or DB_COLLATE values in config.php? See here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#database-character-set

Comment: Instead of "special characters", can you tell us which specific characters aren't showing? Also, you might want to look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30074553/231316) which explains that UTF-8 in MySQL isn't exactly what people think it is. There's also a [WordPress specific blog post](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/02/the-utf8mb4-upgrade/) on their upgrade to full UTF-8.

Comment: sure, in https://www.clinicapacifico.cl/sucursales/ instead of "Sábado" it shows "SÃ¡bado" so basically any accent or ñ it wont show. I tried wpconfig but nothing, db_charset is set to utf8.

Comment: change that to "utf8mb4"

Comment: same result, i changed it to:

define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');

define('DB_COLLATE', '');