# Problems with utf8 insert in database with python

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have created a python script which reads `.xlsx` files with `openpyxl` and send data to MySQL database.
The database interclassement is utf8_unicode_ci.

On this data I get an error:  `Beam 40 x 75`

The error is:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9D\x99\xB8 a...' for column ...
```

It is about the character:

How is it possible to replace "not allowed" chars by spaces (and not every other like `é`, `è`, ... which cause no problems?

Comment: This is a perfectly good Unicode character: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d678/index.htm - I think the problem is rather caused by the fact your database uses the obsolete "mb3" type instead of utf8mb4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MATHEMATICAL MONOSPACE CAPITAL I` is available in "UTF-8", which is available in MySQL's `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, but not `utf8`.

Change the charset for (at least) the column that you are loading that value into.