# Uploading CSV file (UTF-8) with apostrophe's? Text is cutoff after apostrophe, MySQL UTF-8 DB

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, encoding, magento2

I am converting XLSX files into CSV within Excel 2013 (opening the XLSX file, copying relevant data and then saving as CSV). Everything is fine except when uploading the file I've noticed, in our size attribute, that values which have a certain format are not being shown at all.

So if a size value is **6' x 9'** it'll show fine. But if it's like **5' x 7'6** where there is data after the second apostrophe it doesn't show at all. The same goes for values where it's like: **2'3 x 4'5** basically anytime there is an inches (These are sizes in feet & inches) the value won't show.

Note that we are not using **"** for inches so that isn't related.

We're importing into a MySQL database using Magento 2, which has **utf8_general_ci** encoding. I've read of people having a similar issue but couldn't find a clear solution. Does anyone have suspicion of why this is occurring?

**Note:** I've tried changing the encoding by saving as a notepad.exe file (and specifying UTF-8) and it didn't fix this.

Comment: you almost always want `utf8mb4_`, not `utf8_`

Comment: Let's see the `LOAD FILE` statement.  Sounds like it was not configured correctly.

Comment: Those apostrophes are really apostrophes, not left/right single-quote.  So, I don't think the charset is relevant.

Comment: Is it being cut-off when you import into the database?  Or when it is being generated from Excel.  I cannot reproduce the latter (and don't have the tools to examine the former).

Comment: @ysth: Why is that? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64209801/17389

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.