# Django auth + MySQL migrations, row size too large

Tags: python, mysql, django

This migration file fails which is included in the contrib.auth

`/Users/xxx/.virtualenvs/xxxx-0LdyW30-/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length.py`

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0011_update_proxy_permissions'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='user',
            name='first_name',
            field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150, verbose_name='first name'),
        ),
    ]
```

error:

> web_1      | MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1118, 'Row size
> too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting
> BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You
> have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs')

note: I'm using a docker-compose environment

UPDATE: init migrations in django.contrib.auth.models
-- /Users/xxx/.virtualenvs/xxxx-0LdyW30-/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0001_initial.py

```py
import django.contrib.auth.models
from django.contrib.auth import validators
from django.db import migrations, models
from django.utils import timezone


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('contenttypes', '__first__'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Permission',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='name')),
                ('content_type', models.ForeignKey(
                    to='contenttypes.ContentType',
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                    to_field='id',
                    verbose_name='content type',
                )),
                ('codename', models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='codename')),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ['content_type__app_label', 'content_type__model', 'codename'],
                'unique_together': {('content_type', 'codename')},
                'verbose_name': 'permission',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'permissions',
            },
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.PermissionManager()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Group',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('name', models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=80, verbose_name='name')),
                ('permissions', models.ManyToManyField(to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='permissions', blank=True)),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'group',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'groups',
            },
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.GroupManager()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(
                    default=False,
                    help_text='Designates that this user has all permissions without explicitly assigning them.',
                    verbose_name='superuser status'
                )),
                ('username', models.CharField(
                    help_text='Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.', unique=True,
                    max_length=30, verbose_name='username',
                    validators=[validators.UnicodeUsernameValidator()],
                )),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='first name', blank=True)),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='last name', blank=True)),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=75, verbose_name='email address', blank=True)),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(
                    default=False, help_text='Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.',
                    verbose_name='staff status'
                )),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(
                    default=True, verbose_name='active', help_text=(
                        'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting '
                        'accounts.'
                    )
                )),
                ('date_joined', models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='date joined')),
                ('groups', models.ManyToManyField(
                    to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups', blank=True, related_name='user_set',
                    related_query_name='user', help_text=(
                        'The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their '
                        'groups.'
                    )
                )),
                ('user_permissions', models.ManyToManyField(
                    to='auth.Permission', verbose_name='user permissions', blank=True,
                    help_text='Specific permissions for this user.', related_name='user_set',
                    related_query_name='user')
                 ),
            ],
            options={
                'swappable': 'AUTH_USER_MODEL',
                'verbose_name': 'user',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'users',
            },
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

repo url: https://github.com/0mars/biostar-central-docker

```
show create table auth_user
    -> ;
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table     | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| auth_user | CREATE TABLE `auth_user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_superuser` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  `is_staff` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_joined` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: You need to show us the table definition.  And what was being changed in the "migration".

Comment: updated with the initial migration

Comment: I'm sorry; can you find out what `ALTER` statements that code generates.

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: The problem is that this package is in django itself! so I cannot modify it, shall I file a bug report ?

Comment: If the tables are already built, go to the server via phpmyadmin, Workbench, or the mysql commandline tool and get `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Post your custom User model please!

Comment: Check the collation of the table and columns. Make it utf8_general_ci if it's not.

Comment: @AhmedShehab there are no custom models, project is available updated the question

Comment: @RickJames updated!

Comment: Strange; that CREATE TABLE works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Fix:**

Use TextField instead of CharField for first_name

**Maths:**

- The max size of the data that be stored in the MYSQL row is 65535 bytes. (Read more about MySQL row size limitation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html#:%7E:text=The%20internal%20representation%20of%20a,the%20rest%20of%20the%20row.))
- Assuming the database is using utfmb4 character set, it uses 1 to 4 bytes per character. (Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52337457/3065198))
- Assuming that all the characters are using 4 bytes, so a total of 65535/4 = 16383 characters per rows. So the sum of max_length of all the charfield must be less 16383 characters.

To debug this issue properly, check the character set of your database.

Comment: still the error doesn;t make sense at all, first_names usually doesn;t get beyond 150chars

Comment: first solution is impossible: web_1      | django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'first_name' in class 'UserExt' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'User'.

Comment: For me Django was not allowing more than 96 Columns in one table, so I broke up the table into separate (anyways 96 was too much) and then it worked.

Answer (score -1):

In the mysql my.cnf or command settings, a possible solution is to disable innodb_strict_mode.

docker compose example:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --innodb_strict_mode=0
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db_name'
      MYSQL_USER: 'username'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'sa_password'
```

Comment: will have a look now