# is there what are the collation is used for accept emoji in database

Tags: database, collation

I want to know what are the collation type is used for viewing emoji or accept in DB what the reason behind it and how its work?

I need a proper explain about that pls help out of this and moreover what the reason certain collation accept and other why it can't?

Comment: "*how its work*" -  [What is the difference between utf8mb4 and utf8 charsets in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql)